# Can yarn check a particular dependency?

Tags: node.js, npm

So, I'm writing a small script. How can I check does package.json contains some dependency?
Now I do it like this:

```
yarn list --depth=0 | grep "settings" | wc -l
```

Where `settings` is a name of the particular dependency.

It works, but is there a special command for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use `--pattern` flag to filter the list directly, as well as silence the "normal" yarn output with `-s` flag:

```
yarn list -s --pattern "settings"
```

... but you'll still have to count the lines.

Comment: it doesnt work for me 
```>yarn list --depth=0 --pattern="settings"
yarn list v1.1.0
├─ abbrev@1.1.1
├─ accept@2.1.4
├─ acorn-jsx@3.0.1
├─ acorn@5.2.1
├─ agent-base@2.1.1
├─ ajv-keywords@2.1.1
....
```

Comment: it returns more than 1 line. Also, the format of the output looks useless in case when I want to use it in some shell script

Comment: without '=' I have the same result. Does it work for you?

Comment: Obviously. node's v6.12.2 on Windows 10. From your output it looks like the whole 'pattern' flag is skipped for some reason.

Comment: yarn's version's 1.3.2, if that matters.

Comment: In any case, technically your answer is correct. But it gives nothing in my case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to trim extra characters for use in shell scripts, you can use `tail` and `sed` with the existing answer like so:

```sh
yarn list -s --depth=0 --pattern "settings" | tail -n 1 | sed 's/.*@//g'
```

or as part of a script:

```sh
echo "The version is $(yarn list -s --depth=0 --pattern "settings" | tail -n 1 | sed 's/.*@//g')"
```

It works in 3 steps:

1. Use yarn list with silent flag and a depth of 0 (top level dependencies only) and a pattern matching your package name
2. Use `tail` to trim output of previous step to just the last line (shortest dependency name matching pattern comes last)
3. Use `sed` to remove everything before the `@` symbol (the version is after `@`)